# Outlook 2016 UI transparency bug

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, user-interface, transparency

I'm using Outlook 2016 64-bit. Often, when switching to the Outlook window, there'll be a UI glitch that makes elements of the interface transparent. You can see in the sample image below. Disabling hardware graphics acceleration **does not** solve the problem, contrary to some suggestions. My Outlook is apparently up-to-date.  So are my drivers. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Outlook, and applying repairs or fixes, but nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.

Also, I just discovered that the bug **even occurs in safe mode**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Re-create an Outlook profile for this user or perform a repair with Office. Then check if this issue persists:
Create an Outlook profile

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d

Start your Windows client and Outlook in safe mode, check the result.